# Can't Figure Out How to Deploy MERN Stack Application to Render. sh: 1: react-scripts: not found Error

Tags: javascript, deployment, package.json, mern

Previous Heroku Free Tier user here. I'm forced to try other deployment options due to Heroku removing their Free Tier a few months back. I've deployed a few MERN stack applications to Heroku in the past, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to deploy to [render.com](https://render.com). Currently I have my app I'm trying to deploy ([here](https://github.com/tgoandrex/wheres-waldo)) working perfectly in my local environment, but the build fails when I try deploying to Render as a Web Service. The error I get is the following:

```
Jan 17 11:38:15 PM  > wheres_waldo@0.1.0 build /opt/render/project/src
Jan 17 11:38:15 PM  > react-scripts build
Jan 17 11:38:15 PM  
Jan 17 11:38:15 PM  sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
```

In my package.json I clearly have `"react-scripts": "^5.0.1"` in the dependencies so I do not understand why the error happens here. I try changing the 'start' and 'build' scripts in `package.json` to other commands like 'npm run build' or 'npm start' but no luck. I cannot find any good documents on MERN stack deployment either for Render. Is there a way of making this work or should I try another free option elsewhere that provides better support for my stack?

Comment: It looks like you first have to call `npm ci`. What did you set as build command and start command?

Answer (score -1):

Besides moving react-scripts out of devDependencies, try changing your node version in your server side package.json in the "engines" section to the following (instead of having a specific version selected):
"node": "^8 || ^10",

https://github.com/StephenGrider/FullstackReactCode/issues/14#issuecomment-928936921

Comment: Only have the one package.json in the root folder that has dependencies for both front end and back end. Is it correct in this case to have two package.json files?

Comment: No I don't think so